CKEditor5 - Add class or classes to built-in elements like the p-tag
I feel like this should be simple but CKs docs are so dense and fragmented that I can't find a way to do what I feel should be a simple task!
I just want to add a class to existing elements like the paragraph tag.
<p class="cke-paragraph">
  ...content
</p>

or
<ul class="cke-list">
  <li>...
</ul>

Thats it! Thats all I want to do... I feel like that should be something relatively simple that should/could go in the configuration but I can't see it. It's mildly infuriating that I'm on like the 67th tab trying to figure this out and I've build reasonably advanced plugins for this thing and still can't figure this out.
